# How to Store the Images into PostgreSQL using wso2esb and wso2dss

Tags: encoding, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, bytea, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.7.0 , wso2dss 3.0.1 and posgresql 9.1.4
In postgresql i used data type bytea and in wso2dss 3.0.1 we dont have bytea so i used binary data type while i am inserting via dss it inserting the values but selecting query is not working 
In wso2esb or wso2dss has any example for this
data is saving in  this format `x5c78`
 but selection time its not showing in dss what is the issue

```
<query id="insert_testing_query" useConfig="default">
      <sql>INSERT INTO public.testing(username,password,remoteaddress,result,img) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)</sql>
      <param name="username" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="password" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="remoteaddress" ordinal="3" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="result" ordinal="4" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="img" ordinal="5" sqlType="BINARY"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="insert_testing_operation">
      <call-query href="insert_testing_query">
         <with-param name="result" query-param="result"/>
         <with-param name="remoteaddress" query-param="remoteaddress"/>
         <with-param name="username" query-param="username"/>
         <with-param name="img" query-param="img"/>
         <with-param name="password" query-param="password"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the select query the element should be in the xs:base64 type. Please refer [this doc](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/Data+Types). Here is a sample dataservices configuration for select query.

```
    <query id="select_testing_query" useConfig="default">
      <sql>SELECT username,password,remoteaddress,result,img FROM public.testing</sql>
      <result element="SAMPLECollection" rowName="SAMPLE">
         <element column="username" name="username" xsdType="xs:string"/>
         <element column="password" name="password" xsdType="xs:string"/>
         <element column="remoteaddress" name="remoteaddress" xsdType="xs:string"/>
         <element column="result" name="result" xsdType="xs:string"/>
         <element column="img" name="img" xsdType="xs:base64"/>
      </result>
  </query>
   <operation name="select_testing_operation">
      <call-query href="select_testing_query"/>
   </operation>
```